# Getting OS X Storage Device List Using IOServiceGetMatchingServices

Tags: macos, iokit

I need to get the list of physical storage devices on an OS X system. IOServiceGetMatchingServices using the kIOStorageClass key gives me a list of all volumes, not all hardware storage devices. How do I do this?

Comment: what is a storage device that isn't a volume, are you looking for unmounted storage as well? or like block devices... etc.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little ambiguous (do you want whole drives, partitions, all of the above?), I suggest firing up the **IORegistryExplorer** utility (comes with XCode) and figuring out which class of device you want. I can tell you that each whole *drive* normally corresponds to an `IOBlockStorageDriver`, so maybe that's the class you want to match. It will then have an `IOMedia` client representing the whole device. It in turn will have a partition scheme client, which has an `IOMedia` client for each partition, unless it's not partitioned.

Answer (score 0):

To get list of physical storage device you can match for kIOATABlockStorageDeviceClass. Following code obtains iterator for block storage devices.

```
IOReturn        error       = kIOReturnSuccess;
io_iterator_t   iter        = MACH_PORT_NULL;
error = IOServiceGetMatchingServices (  kIOMasterPortDefault,
                                      IOServiceMatching ( kIOATABlockStorageDeviceClass ),
                                      &iter );
```